# C: Loop jumps from 0 to 1000 and therefore doesn't loop. Why?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

im studying for a exam and the task says: (Translated from german to english) 
Expand the program to show 1000 different "average values".

So it loops 0-1000 to get 1 "average value" and it should do that 1000 times so i have 1000 different values. The problem is that the first for-loop goes from 0-1000 immediately and prints only one value.

```
int i, r, j = 0;
long sum, total = 0; 


for (j = 0; j < 1000; j++);  { // jumps here
    srand(time(NULL)); 

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        r = rand();
        //printf("%d %d\n", i, r);
        sum += r;
    }
    total += sum;
    printf("%d\n", total);
}
printf("Durchschnitt sum = %li\n", sum / 1000);
printf("Durchschnitt total = %li", total / 1000);
```

Comment: `for (j = 0; j < 1000; j++); {`... remove that last semicolon! The `for` statement ended there and the rest of your block just executed as a single block independent of the `for`.

Comment: Remove the semicolon after the first loop.

Comment: Check your compiler’s manual page or other documentation for warning switches to enable, and use those switches routinely. (If you are compiling with GCC, add “-Wmost”.) Good compilers would have warned you about the misplaced semicolon. (GCC says “warning: for loop has empty body”.)

Also, when you provide code in questions in the future, please provide the [complete (but minimal) source code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can compile it.

Comment: The semicolon did the trick! Thanks.

Comment: Aside: move `srand(time(NULL));` out of the loop. It should be called once only in the program. Your way, each `j` loop probably produces the same result, unless the time has ticked by 1 second.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but there is no loop. So first fix the loop, *then* move the srand() outside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (j = 0; j < 1000; j++) { // jumps here
```

instead of

```
for (j = 0; j < 1000; j++);  { // jumps here
```